# Ideal full wave rectifier for 100V @2A

Tags: rectifier

I have a 50Vrms sinewave (100Hz and 2A), I rectify it using a full wave rectifier.

Are their away to implement an( **ideal** full wave rectifier) with this specifications using LM358P (its input is 0 and 15V).
 [image]
I think it is impossible with op amp but I asked, maybe someone advise my with another way.

Comment: There are high voltage op amps, Apex makes some very high voltage amps, and even TI has a relatively inexpensive part, the OPA454 which is good for up to about 100V rail to rail.  The real question is what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite inconvenient to drive the gates of MOSFETs to improve the efficiency of a full-wave rectifier. [Here's](http://www.irf.com/technical-info/whitepaper/tp-080527.pdf) a paper where the authors have investigated this: "**A novel high efficient approach to input bridges**".

The losses at 2A are not all that great (a couple percent), especially if you use Schottky diodes, so it's probably not worthwhile to attempt this at present.

You might find "synchronous" a useful search term in your further research. That's normally what active power rectifiers are called, whereas "ideal rectifier" normally is in reference to signal processing absolute value circuits.

Comment: Interesting paper.